# I upgraded fron 12.04 to 12.10 and can not find my pictures

Tags: upgrade

I did an upgrade installation (not new) but now I can not find my pictures. And the reason I did the upgrade version was to keep all of my "old files" intact.

How can I find my pictures?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GDmap](http://gdmap.sourceforge.net/) to map out your hard drive and break down files by type and physical size. It should make it easier to locate your pictures.

[image]